# Include doesn't work with Select in query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to use `Include()` in a query but it doesn't work as I expect.
I have a table called `Bes` who has this columns:

- Id
- Name
- Pesta
- CeId
- OpId

The `CeId` and `OpId` are foreign keys to this tables:

Ces:

- Id
- Name

Ops:

- Id
- Name

I want to run this query (which works but doesn't fill the `Ces` and `Ops` tables)

```
var bes = await _context.Bes
            .Include(x => x.Ops)
            .Include(x => x.Ces)
            .Where(x => besWithXPs.Contains(x.Pesta))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Pesta)
            .Select(x => x.First())
            .ToListAsync();
```

I try to use this query without the `Select()` and the `Ops` and `Ces` where fill but I only want one Bes per Pesta (that's why the `GroupBy` and `Select`)

Anyone knows what is happening?

Btw I'm using Entity Framework Core with .NET Core 2

Comment: As I understand Entity Framework Core, you can query into nested objects without eagerly loading them. Thus, I think the `Include()` comes after the `Select()`.

Comment: No, that is not the problem

Comment: Reading your problem statement again, I think you are trying to do [Explicit Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Ces Ce { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Ods Od { get; set; }
```

to your model in order to let include them and then do:

```
var bes = await _context.Bes.AsNotracking()
        .Include(x => x.Ops)
        .Include(x => x.Ces)
        .Where(x => besWithXPs.Contains(x.Pesta))
        .GroupBy(x => x.Pesta)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

1 - What AsNoTracking Does:
Entity Framework exposes a number of performance tuning options to help you optimise the performance of your applications. One of these tuning options is .AsNoTracking(). This optimisation allows you to tell Entity Framework not to track the results of a query. This means that Entity Framework performs no additional processing or storage of the entities which are returned by the query. However, it also means that you can't update these entities without reattaching them to the tracking graph.

2 - Change ".Select(x => x.First()).ToListAsync();" to ".FirstOrDefaultAsync();". Use .Select only if you want to get some of the properties or if you need a new class filled with the data that you receive.